How to extract a substring between a string and Nth occurance?
I need to extract a substring from a string and Nth occurance
Example:
Abc-defg-hijkl-mno pqr-1245
Abc-defg-hijkl-mno ab-8748

The output should be
pqr
ab

I tried
substr(text,
       instr(text, ’Abc-defg-hijkl-mno’),
       instr(text, ’-’) - instr(text, ’Abc-defg-hijkl-mno’))

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

You mention "Nth" occurrence, but what is the value of N here?  Do you always want the last occurrence, or could it be somewhere else in a larger string?

yes I need the last occurrence only

Do you mean "find last -. Get the string just before it."

If what you want is between the latest space and the latest '-':
substr(s, instr(s,' ', -1)+1, instr(s, '-', -1) - instr(s,' ', -1) -1)


We can use REGEXP_SUBSTR() here with a capture group:
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(val, '([a-z]+)-[0-9]+$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
FROM yourTable;

The regex pattern used matches the last component of the string (ending with $ marker), and captures the leading letter portion before the hyphen in the first capture group.
Here is a running demo.
